# How to install vim with lua using brew?

Tags: macos, vim, lua, installation, homebrew

I want to install vim with **Lua** via brew, but I couldn't.

**I've tried:**

```
brew install vim --with-lua
```

But I got an error:

> Error: invalid option: --with-lua

**Then, I tried:**

```
brew info vim
```

But there is no option.

Although I reinstalled brew, the error has been caused.
What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Homebrew no longer provides options for packages. They've been intentionally removed because they're often poorly tested.

The default `vim` package has support for Lua, as does the `macvim` package if you prefer a GUI. It should be simple enough to do a `brew install vim` or `brew install macvim` after doing a `brew update`.

Comment: I could install vim with Lua trying it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew install lua vim
```

Comment: Please give some explanation with your answer.